# in PHP does a try, throw, catch kill the script?

Tags: php

Does the Try, throw, catch exceptions kill a php script. For Example:

```
try{
    if(0 != 0){
      throw new Exception('of course it equals 0!');

} catch (Exception $e){
   echo 'Exception was Caught: ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

If the Exception is thrown and is caught where does the code go from the echo? Can it ever escape that and continue or is the script killed at that point? I'm asking for security reasons. If I was to say create a login script and I use the try catch to verify username, etc... and the username is wrong and the exception is thrown is the code finished at that catch point?

Comment: Have you tried the code and put an echo statement under the try-catch ?

Comment: Why haven't you consulted the documentation and tried first? (it has nothing to do with security for sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In every language when you catch the exception the script continues to the next line. In your example the execution will continue withe next statement after the echo, which in your case will be the first expression after the curly brace that is closing the catch block.